# Debugger cannot find module 'StyleSheet'. My app runs fine. Path points fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, react-native, visual-studio-code

Very strange error that I cannot seem to solve.

React-native and node.js and VS Code

To get VS Code to get this far I used the line, yarn add babel-cli

Error I'm Getting:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:39061/61f6ad51-d255-463a-a0ad-b686be9b8b0d
Object {dataReducer: Object, reducerSPY: Object, userApp: Object}
home.js:31
Error: Cannot find module 'StyleSheet'
module.js:555
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.get StyleSheet [as StyleSheet] (c:\AndroidEverything\AndroidStudioProjects\Property2\AwesomeProject\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\react-native\react-native-implementation.js:98:29)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:/AndroidEverything/AndroidStudioProjects/Property2/AwesomeProject/app/components/home.js:195:16)
```

Strange because:

- My app runs fine
- If I comment out this line all other imports are found, just
  StyleSheet.
- All files are as I expected in its location. This seems buggy?

home.js(which is called by App.js)

```
import {
    FlatList,
    View,
    Text,
    ActivityIndicator,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
```

launch.json

```
 {
     "type": "node",
     "request": "launch",
     "name": "Launch Program",
     "program": "${workspaceFolder}/App.js",
     "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
 },
```

package.json

```
{
"name": "AwesomeProject",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"devDependencies": {
"jest-expo": "25.0.0",
"react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
"react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
},
"main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
"scripts": {
"start": "react-native-scripts start",
"eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
"android": "react-native-scripts android",
"ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
"test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
 },
"jest": {
"preset": "jest-expo"
 },
"dependencies": {
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"expo": "^25.0.0",
"react": "16.0.0",
"react-dom": "16.0.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0",
"react-navigation": "^1.5.1",
"react-redux": "^5.0.7",
"redux": "^3.7.2",
"redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
"save": "^2.3.2"
}
}
```

Any ideas where to keep digging? launch.json file? connectivity? yarn? or a spelling error?

UPDATE:

Removed the line about babel since i'm using yarn for node.js and Expo to run on android. error has changed to:

```
    path\Property2\AwesomeProject\App.js:1

(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, 
 { Component } from 'react';
                                                          ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
```

using yarn upgrade jest-expo@25.1.0-beta.0

```
 warning "expo > react-native-maps@0.19.0" has incorrect peer dependency 
 "react-native@0.51.0".
 warning " > react-native@0.52.0" has incorrect peer dependency 
 "react@16.2.0".
 warning "jest-expo > babel-jest@22.4.3" has unmet peer dependency "babel-
 core@^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0-0".
 [4/4] Rebuilding all packages...
 success Saved lockfile.
 success Saved 1 new dependency.
 └─ jest-expo@25.1.0-beta.0
 warning "jest-expo" is already in "devDependencies". Please remove existing 
 entry first before adding it to "dependencies".
```

Comment: is it expo based project or react-native cli?

Comment: please add package.json file in your question

Comment: I am not sure about expo v cli. I used yarn for the install. 

Couldnt figure out by googling either.
File updated

Comment: I am using Expo on my android and running yarn to run node.js. I deleted the line in my launch.json file that mentioned the babel cli, and now I'm getting an error. will post in the body.

Comment: try this command `yarn upgrade jest-expo@25.1.0-beta.0` and let me know the result.

Comment: Added my current error to post when using yarn upgrade, but I'll mess around with it this morning.

Comment: At this point I feel like I might need to do surgery. Should I be removing and adding manually? Or is this unnecessary complexity and cause for risk?

Comment: you know now you should create a fresh project and try or may be post your project code let other people try to see the whole code so people can give you review what is happening exactly.

Comment: After spending another day working on this, I am believing that I 'need' babel. I have messed around with it, using npm installs and other.

There always seemed to be an 'import' error. 

Any idea why this "import" error is coming up so frequently? I've read things about ES6, but I dont know where that would need to be consistent- and where that is failing.

Comment: I believe the solution is in launch.json or the import {StyleSheets} from 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

This is the minimal package.json file of my react native sample project just created to test your cases. Basically you are using [**CRNA**](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) (*create-react-native-app*) to create your project this is a **expo client**. See my package.json file below:

```
{
    "name": "AwesomeProject",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "devDependencies": {
      "react-native-scripts": "1.13.1",
      "jest-expo": "26.0.0",
      "react-test-renderer": "16.3.0-alpha.1"
    },
    "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-native-scripts start",
      "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
      "android": "react-native-scripts android",
      "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
      "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
      "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "expo": "^26.0.0",
      "react": "16.3.0-alpha.1",
      "react-native": "0.54.0"
    }
  }
```

You don't need to add **babel-cli** for basic project read its [**usage here**](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) but if you still need then add it to your dev-dependencies. Also **react-dom** you still not need because its for reactjs projects not for react-native.

My suggestion is try to read before you start your project and go step by step then you'll not stuck in some irrelevant issue.

Comment: Going to restart this process updating npm and reinstalling with 'npm install -g create-react-native-app' I think there is an incompatibility along the way that takes finding, but I believe this build is SOL. Do you have a suggestion on where to start. Goal is to use my android phone expo, VS code, react-native. I was reading there is a chrome debugger solution that I might go to instead.

Comment: create-react-native-app is an expo client, yeah you can access debugger for more info [See Here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html). As you are starting with react native my suggestion is read more before code more.

Comment: ok. I will read more. I will report back in a few days when I get everything working again.

Comment: React developer tools worked to connect the debugger. It seems the problem is somewhere in VS code, and babel wasnt helping me.

If I figure out a solution to getting this working in VS code, I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

What node version are you using? I am asking this because in your question you mentioned the error the code is throwing

path\Property2\AwesomeProject\App.js:1

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import React, 
 { Component } from 'react';
                                                          ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
```

and it seems like code is having trouble resolving import statements.So it may be that yout babel is not able resolve this new syntax.

Comment: Thank you, let me try a rebuild and get the debugger working on a fresh app.